# how to keep same "env" when running bash from Jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins

I have Jenkins job which is connecting to remote host via ssh and runs a bash command.

I can run the same bash command via terminal by logging into remote linux machine. But If I do so , I see env variables are different when I tried printing printenv.

Now, if I run the same bash command from Jenkins over ssh execCommand I see bit different set of env variables.
Is there any way, I can make that bash run using same env variables, no matter where I am running it from?

Comment: You might need to migrate environment variables out of `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` and into `~/.bashrc`: Jenkins runs non-interactively on the node, so bash [does not load](https://serverfault.com/a/376264/204816) the profile.

Comment: just copy the env variables from set them in Jenkins using PATH=PATH:/newVariables:/....